# Gentoo emerge blocked package issue

Tags: gentoo, portage

It seems that package clamav prevents itself from upgrade. Portage is up to date and portage tree is synchronized. 
Is anybody knows ho to solve this issue with blocking package in gentoo?

```
# emerge -uDpv clamav

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild     U  ] app-arch/bzip2-1.0.6-r7::gentoo [1.0.6-r6::gentoo] USE="-static -static-libs" 764 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/file-5.25::gentoo [5.22::gentoo] USE="-python -static-libs -zlib" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 (-pypy) -python3_3 -python3_4" 723 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/expat-2.1.1-r2::gentoo [2.1.0-r5::gentoo] USE="unicode -examples -static-libs" 396 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/debianutils-4.7::gentoo [4.4::gentoo] USE="-static" 153 KiB
[ebuild     U ~] dev-libs/libgpg-error-1.24::gentoo [1.22::gentoo] USE="-common-lisp -nls -static-libs" 766 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libffi-3.2.1::gentoo [3.0.13-r1::gentoo] USE="-debug -pax_kernel -static-libs {-test}" 919 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] sys-devel/m4-1.4.17::gentoo [1.4.16::gentoo] USE="-examples" 1,123 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] app-misc/pax-utils-1.1.6::gentoo [1.0.3::gentoo] USE="-caps -debug% -python -seccomp%" 633 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] app-arch/tar-1.28-r1::gentoo [1.27.1-r2::gentoo] USE="acl -minimal -nls (-selinux) -static -xattr" 2,631 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2h-r2::gentoo [1.0.2h::gentoo] USE="-asm -bindist -gmp -kerberos -rfc3779 -sctp -sslv2% -sslv3% -static-libs {-test} -tls-heartbeat -vanilla -zlib" CPU_FLAGS_X86="-sse2" 0 KiB
[ebuild     U ~] app-eselect/eselect-python-20160516::gentoo [20160222::gentoo] 46 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libpcre-8.38-r1:3::gentoo [8.38:3::gentoo] USE="bzip2 cxx readline (unicode) -jit -libedit -pcre16 -pcre32 -recursion-limit -static-libs -zlib" 1,526 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-util/gtk-doc-am-1.25::gentoo [1.24::gentoo] 658 KiB
[ebuild     U ~] dev-lang/python-2.7.12:2.7::gentoo [2.7.11-r2:2.7::gentoo] USE="gdbm ncurses readline ssl threads (wide-unicode) xml (-berkdb) -build -doc -examples -hardened -ipv6 -libressl -sqlite -tk -wininst" 12,114 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libxml2-2.9.4:2::gentoo [2.9.3:2::gentoo] USE="python readline -debug -examples -icu -ipv6 -lzma -static-libs {-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 -python3_3 -python3_4 (-python3_5)" 5,249 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] app-admin/perl-cleaner-2.20::gentoo [2.19::gentoo] 7 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libxslt-1.1.29::gentoo [1.1.28-r5::gentoo] USE="crypt -debug -examples -python -static-libs" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 3,349 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] sys-devel/gettext-0.19.7::gentoo [0.19.4::gentoo] USE="acl cxx ncurses -cvs -doc -emacs -git -java -nls -openmp -static-libs" 18,785 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/glib-2.46.2-r3:2::gentoo [2.46.2-r2:2::gentoo] USE="-dbus -debug (-fam) -mime (-selinux) -static-libs -systemtap {-test} -utils -xattr" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 0 KiB
[ebuild     U  ] app-antivirus/clamav-0.99::gentoo [0.98.7::gentoo] USE="bzip2 -clamdtop -iconv -ipv6 (-libressl) -metadata-analysis-api -milter (-selinux) -static-libs (-uclibc)" 15,594 KiB
[blocks B      ] <app-antivirus/clamav-0.99 ("<app-antivirus/clamav-0.99" is hard blocking app-antivirus/clamav-0.99)

Total: 20 packages (20 upgrades), Size of downloads: 65,428 KiB
Conflict: 1 block (1 unsatisfied)

 * Error: The above package list contains packages which cannot be
 * installed at the same time on the same system.

  (app-antivirus/clamav-0.99:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    app-antivirus/clamav required by @selected
    clamav
    app-antivirus/clamav required by (mail-filter/qmail-scanner-2.08:0/0::gentoo, installed)

# grep -R clamav /etc/portage/*
/etc/portage/package.use:app-antivirus/clamav   -* crypt
/etc/portage/package.use:mail-filter/qmail-scanner spamassassin  clamav
/etc/portage/package.use:mail-filter/dspam      clamav daemon mysql procmail virtual-users
/etc/portage/package.use:app-antivirus/clamav   crypt bzip2 
# grep clamav /etc/make.conf 
#
```

Comment: You could try to add qmail-scanner to the lhings to check (`emerge -uDpv clamav qmail-scanner`). If that does not help: Have you tried temporarily uninstalling clamav and then installing it again? Also: The most recent version of clamav seems to be `0.99.2`. Maybe it works after another `emerge --sync`

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Understand the output you are seeing:

1. `mail-filter/qmail-scanner` requires less than version 0.99.  Notice that you have version 0.98.7 installed
2. The new version of `app-antivirus/clamav` is 0.99.
3. Portage is hard blocking `app-antivirus/clamav` because 0.99 is greater than 0.98.7

### Fix

You need a version of `mail-filter/qmail-scanner` greater than 2.08.  Since there isn't one, you have two options:

1. Leave clamav alone until qmail-scanner is updated. See [mail-filter/qmail-scanner-2.11 version bump](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489156)
2. Modify the `mail-filter/qmail` ebuild in a [local overlay](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Overlay/Local_overlay) to accept newer versions of `app-antivirus/clamav`

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

```
emerge -C app-antivirus/clamav
emerge -1 app-antivirus/clamav
# continue with the update
```

#### The problems:

1. newer `app-antivirus/clamav` version (0.99) blocks all previous versions in `DEPEND` section
2. thus the newer version cannot be built if the previous one exists
3. portage is unable to cope with this situation itself, because if it uninstalls the older version
   and compilation of the newer version fails, you will end up with no clamav at all
4. portage provides user unfriendly message about this problem

#### Notes:

`mail-filter/qmail-scanner` is innocent